# :Condition statement and Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get these statements to work:

```
@all_ratings = ["G","PG","PG-13","R"]
@valid_ratings = params["ratings"]
@movies = Movie.find(:all ,  :conditions => {@valid_ratings[:rating.upcase] => "1"}   )
```

but I am getting the error:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

when I should be getting a match.

An example input is:

```
"ratings"=>{"PG-13"=>"1"}
```

Where am I going wrong?

---

More info:

The table has three fields, the title, release date, and rating, and is very simple. The options for rating are stated above in `@all_ratings`.

Comment: What is the actual value of `@valid_ratings[:rating.upcase]`? It’s probably `nil`. Also note that unless you are using Rails 2.3 or earlier, you should avoid the `find(:all, ...)` syntax, as it is deprecated in Rails 4.

Comment: If you can describe your table description, it would be perfect..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 3.x:

```
@all_ratings = ["G","PG","PG-13","R"]
@valid_ratings = params["ratings"]
# Is @valid_ratings the same as you example, "ratings"=>{"PG-13"=>"1"}?
# It would be easiest to pass a subset of @all_ratings such that the params
# get converted to something like this: "ratings"=>["G", "PG"]
Movie.where(:rating => valid_ratings).all
# SQL: SELECT * FROM movies WHERE rating IN ('G','PG')
```

I am not sure what you are trying to with `:rating.upcase`.  Is there a variable named rating? `:rating` is a symbol. `upcase` is not a method on Symbol.

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that you `@valid_ratings` in `nil`

You probably trying doing this?

```
@valid_ratings = Rating.find(params["ratings"])
```

Comment: You inferred a whole lot about the OP’s object model here.

Comment: My model is Movie, rating is a field inside of it

Comment: Rating.find is going to return a single Rating.  find_all would return an array.  As @Lilluda5 mentioned, she wants to return Movies with the given ratings.